# Name for Theorem 3.27 from baby Rudin?

Tags: real-analysis, terminology

Rudin rarely gives names to the theorems in this book.  Theorem 3.27 states if
$\{a_n\}$ is a monotonically decreasing sequence of  positive reals, then

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\,\text{ converges}\iff\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^ka_{2^k} \text{ converges}.$$

Comment: nevertheless he chose to mention it in the index page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is called the Cauchy condensation test. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test).

Comment: Very informative. Thank you.

Comment: When in doubt,  it's probably named after Cauchy :)

Comment: He's one of the usual suspects. Along with Euler and Gauss.